# unable to load google chart from another html file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-visualization

Im building a simple web page presenting a simple google pie chart according to data passed with JSstorage. the chart is located in another html file. Im trying to populate a `div` with the chart using `AJAX`.

the button that activates the drawing process:

```
<input type="button" name="showChart" value="Show Chart" onclick="drawChart()">
```

the `div` that will be populated with the chart:

```
<div id="placeForChart" style="width:800; height:700">
     google chart goes here
</div>
```

the function that being called upon button click :

```
 function drawChart()
            {
                $.jStorage.set("costsArr",costsArr);
                document.getElementById('placeForChart'.innerHTML = loadChart('chart.html'));
                function loadChart(href)
                {
                    console.log("load chart function was called..");
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", href, false);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                    return xmlhttp.responseXML;
                }
            }
```

and finally the `chart.html`, which is pretty much the standard google's example, with modified content passed using JSstorage.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var costsArr = $.jStorage.get('costsArr');

            google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {

                // Create the data table.
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
                data.addRows([
                    ['food', costsArr[0]],
                    ['clothes', costsArr[2]],
                    ['house holds', costsArr[1]],
                    ['other', costsArr[3]]

                ]);

                var options = {'title':'your expenses',
                    'width':500,
                    'height':400};

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will throw a syntax error:

```
document.getElementById('placeForChart'.innerHTML = loadChart('chart.html'));
```

Your closing parenthesis for the `getElementById` call is in the wrong place.  It should be:

```
document.getElementById('placeForChart').innerHTML = loadChart('chart.html');
```

I suspect that you will need to strip any `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags from chart.html.  Also, you should probably load the visualization API on your main page and use a load event handler in chart.html to draw the chart.

Comment: thanks for the answer. you mean i should save the chart.html as JS file and get rid of all the tags, to make it plane javascript file?

Comment: You could do that, but then why not just include the javascript normally and draw the chart in whatever event handler you are using to make the AJAX call?